# TinyMCE adds <span> when setting style/class i Firefox

Tags: drupal, tinymce, drupal-7, wysiwyg, drupal-theming

I'm using TinyMCE 3.4.6 in a Drupal 7 installation and having problems with adding styles / classes to block-element in Firefox.

**Test:**

1. Add text "Header"
2. Mark it and select block-element "Header 2"
3. Mark it and select style "header-green"

**Expected result in Firefox / Actual result in Chrome:**

```
<h2 class="header-green">Header</h2>
```

**Actual result in Firefox:**

```
<h2><span class="header-green">Header</span></h2>
```

Any ideas what is wrong here and how to fix it? All CSS is based on being able to set classes on elements in the WYSIWYG.

Comment: Use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) along with the [WYSIWYG module)(http://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg), it works much better and has very good integration with other modules (e.g. Media)

Comment: Testing CKEditor but can't get it to use my CSS Styles I denfine under WYSIWYG Profile. Strange...

Comment: CKEditor made the trick, it works much better and feels more stable. Thanks for the tip. We've used TinyMCE for WYSIWYG for several years but from now on I think CK will be our wysiwyg editor of choice.

Comment: No probs, CKEditor is the best WYSIWYG for Drupal in my opinion. If you want image browsing look at either a combination of the IMCE and IMCE WYSIWYG Bridge modules, or the media and media browser modules. They're both very good at what they do

Comment: Yep, already using IMCE and even tho it's pretty ugly it does the job.